# AWS S3 POST issue

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Using this version of the [createPresignedPost property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property) in javascript SDK (I understand this is an older SDK...I'm forced to use it due to node version) I'm generating POST headers for a file upload.

When I set these headers in Postman I get the following error:

> Bucket POST must contain a field named 'key'.

[image: Bucket POST must contain a field named 'key']

When I specify a 'key' I get a new error:

> Invalid according to Policy: Extra input fields: key.

[image: Invalid according to Policy: Extra input fields]

Any idea what this is about and how I can get AWS to play nice so I can finally upload a file?

I do have the file as the last parameter as mentioned in other similar questions
[image: screenshot of postman]

Comment: Include text, not images.

Comment: What exactly is it about the images that aren't helpful? I included both the text in my question and screenshots of the full message for context which should help in both the quality and understanding of the question I was asking.

Comment: You're right, you did include the text of the errors. That wasn't 100% clear initially because the text and image in the 2nd scenario were coalesced accidentally (I edited the post to fix that).

Comment: Ah gotcha, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I wasn't passing my key correctly originally.

Originally I was passing it like so:

```
const params = {
      Bucket: BUCKET, // replace with your bucket name
      Expires: 3600, // URL validity (1 hour in this case)
      Key: uploadFileKey
    };

s3.createPresignedPost(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        
      } else {
          console.log('data', data);
      }
    });
```

which didn't return the key back in the fields:

```
{
url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/some-endpoint',
fields: {
    bucket: 'my-bucket',
    'X-Amz-Algorithm': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
    'X-Amz-Credential': 'SOMECREDENTIAL/20231020/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request',
    'X-Amz-Date': '20231020T143349Z',
    Policy: 'SOMEPOLICY=',
    'X-Amz-Signature': 'SOMESIGNATURE'
    }
}
```

I needed to do the following instead:

```
const params = {
      Bucket: BUCKET, // replace with your bucket name
      Expires: 3600, // URL validity (1 hour in this case)
      Fields: {
        key: targetFilePath,
      },
    };

s3.createPresignedPost(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        
      } else {
          console.log('data', data);
      }
    });
```

which DID return the key back in the fields thus allowing me to add the key field in Postman and successfully post my file

```
{
url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/some-endpoint',
fields: {
    key: 'my-key'
    bucket: 'my-bucket',
    'X-Amz-Algorithm': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
    'X-Amz-Credential': 'SOMECREDENTIAL/20231020/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request',
    'X-Amz-Date': '20231020T143349Z',
    Policy: 'SOMEPOLICY=',
    'X-Amz-Signature': 'SOMESIGNATURE'
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `s3.createPresignedPost` is not really asynchronous and the return value from calling `s3.createPresignedPost` is actually the data itself that you get in the callback.